# Using Roman Numerals and Suppress Number for Introductory Chapter Only

Tags: sectioning, formatting, amsart, unnumbered-sections

I am trying to duplicate the following structure only using the amsart class instead:

[image: image 1] [image: image 2]

In particular, notice how the 'Introduction' Chapter uses Roman numerals and The chapter heading does not display the chapter number. This is what I wish to emulate. However, since I am **required** to use the amsart class, I want to replicate this behaviour with sections and subsections instead of chapters and section. I tried the following:

```
 \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} % Use Roman numerals for Introduction
    
    \section{Introduction} % I also tried \section*{Introduction}

    \subsection{Some Subsection}


    \setcounter{section}{0}

    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} % Reset to Arabic numerals for main chapters

    \section{First Section}

    \subsection{Another Subsection}
```

But it fails to produce the desired output. I would very much appreciate any assistance. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section number in the section title is formatted by the macro `\@seccntformat`, so you have to temporarily disable that to omit it.
For example like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\@seccntformat##1{}
  \section{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

    \mysection{Introduction}

    \subsection{Some Subsection}
```

I hope using `\section` inside a group doesn't have any nasty side effects. Otherwise the original definition must be saved and restored, like

```
\newcommand\origseccntformat{}% check that we can use this command
\makeatletter
\let\origseccntformat\@seccntformat
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{%
  \def\@seccntformat##1{}
  \section{#1}
  \let\@seccntformat\origseccntformat
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this with titlesec package

\documentclass{amsart}      % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle\quad}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{} % Use Roman numerals for Introduction
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}} % Use Roman numerals for Introduction

```
\section{Introduction} % I also tried \section*{Introduction}

\subsection{Some Subsection}


\setcounter{section}{0}
```

\renewcommand{\thesection}{Chapter \arabic{section}: } % Reset to Arabic numerals for main chapters
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}} % Reset to Arabic numerals for main chapters

```
\section{First Section}

\subsection{Another Subsection}
```

\end{document}